# Python: replace minimized special character with `regular` alternative

Tags: python, python-3.x, special-characters

In given a list of strings:

`["duplex 4 pièces 84 m²", "zapatos nº 37", "toyota rav4 3ª serie 2011"]`

It is required to 'unminimize' characters, i.e. `² -> 2`, `º -> o`, `ª -> a` and so on(there could be other minimized chars).

I was trying to find a way to do this w/o hardcoding all possible cases of replacement. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unidecode` module seems to be effective:

```
>>> import unidecode
>>> unidecode.unidecode('² ª º')
'2 a o'
```

Also `unicodedata` module:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', '² ª º')
'2 a o'
```